# How do I change the speed of text motion when paging up/down in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

When I'm editing a file in Sublime Text 3, if I press Page Down, the text slides down to the next page. How do I change the speed (or not let it scroll at all)?

Comment: To adjust mouse scroll wheel speed instead, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289511/4561887

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Preferences->Settings - User
2. Add the line:

   ```
   "scroll_speed": 1.0
   ```

(Note: this is a JavaScript file. If you add the above line at the end, don't forget to add a comma to the previous line; if you add the line in the middle somewhere, add a comma!)

For the speed (From the Default Settings):

```
// Set to 0 to disable smooth scrolling. Set to a value between 0 and 1 to
// scroll slower, or set to larger than 1 to scroll faster
```