# How do I change the mouse wheel scroll speed in Sublime Text 3 or 4+?

Tags: scroll, sublimetext3, mousewheel

The mouse wheel scrolling in Sublime Text 3, on Linux at least, is reaaally sluggish. It scrolls only 3 lines per mouse wheel encoder tick on my mouse, which feels very slow. In Eclipse, however, it scrolls 8 lines per mouse wheel encoder movement, on the same computer and with the same mouse, which feels much more natural.

How do I increase the scroll speed in Sublime Text 3 to scroll faster?

I have tried changing the `"scroll_speed"` setting in preferences. Ex:

```
"scroll_speed": 10.0, // default is 1.0
```

and it made no difference to the mouse wheel scroll speed! It turns out this setting is for the scroll *animation speed* only, which is animated when you press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to scroll.

<sub>This is a Q&A-style question I'm posting here because [I've searched all over the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=sublime%20text%20scroll%20speed&oq=sublime%20text%20scroll%20speed&aqs=chrome..69i57.3821j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and found this answer nowhere. After figuring it out myself because I got too tired of the scroll speed in Sublime, I want to share it here to help others.</sub>

### Related, but *not* a duplicate:

1. [not a duplicate because it has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with mouse wheel scroll speed; this is for <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> scroll *animation* speed only!] [How do I change the speed of text motion when paging up/down in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168729/how-do-i-change-the-speed-of-text-motion-when-paging-up-down-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac and Windows, see if custom mouse scroll settings exist within your operating system.

For Linux, here's the answer. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04 with Sublime Text 3 and 4.

```bash
# create a file called ".imwheelrc" in your home dir
gedit ~/.imwheelrc
```

Copy and paste the following into it:

```bash
# For Sublime Text
"sublime_text"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

The two `3`s are what set the mouse wheel scroll speed. They are multipliers against the normal speed, so 3 is 3x faster. In my case, one mouse scroll wheel tick now scrolls 9 lines instead of 3, since I have the up and down speeds set to `3` each above.

Now install `imwheel`:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install imwheel
```

Run `imwheel -b "4 5"` to test your settings. When done testing, run `killall imwheel` to kill it, then make your edits to `~/.imwheelrc`, as desired, and run `imwheel -b "4 5"` again for more testing.

Done!

Sublime Text 3 mouse wheel scroll speed fixed in Linux!

---

Note: if you'd like to adjust mouse wheel scroll speed for **Google Chrome** and **Slack** too, here's some more entries:

```bash
# For `google-chrome`
"-chrome"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

# For `slack`
"slack"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

# For Sublime Text 3
"sublime_text"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

This is all part of my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) project on GitHub. You can download just my "~/.imwheelrc" file [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.imwheelrc) or here ([raw](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/master/home/.imwheelrc)), with this command:

```bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/master/home/.imwheelrc
```

## References:

1. My [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) project on GitHub, and [the "~/.imwheelrc" file](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.imwheelrc).

   1. I have my system configured so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (P stands for "touch'P'ad" here) toggles my touch pad on and off, and also toggles my `imwheel` program on and off inversely with the touchpad. See my ["touchpad_toggle.sh"](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/touchpad_toggle.sh) script for that in my eRCaGuy_dotfiles project.
   2. **I've also configured this to run at boot so that my touchpad is always OFF, and my `imwheel` always ON to fix mouse wheel scroll speed in these programs each time I turn on my computer.**
2. My answer on AskUbuntu: ["Permanently fix Chrome scroll speed"](https://askubuntu.com/a/991680/327339)